# Java String pattern

Tags: java, string

I have file text and I need to check if its pattern match. 
The file is in lines like in this example:

```
DOG
blabla
CAT
blablabla
DOG
somethingElse
CAT
DOG
badsad
```

What is the correct way to check if file text is match to this pattern
after CAT can be also DOG or sometext?

Comment: You can use `Character.isUpperCase()` for each letter in the word to see if it's a header.

Comment: but the text also can be UpperCase,

Comment: @user3690901 Then it's ambiguous and therefore impossible.

Comment: You can use `contains()` to check the text string exist or not

Comment: You need a much better problem description. As it stands it sounds like you just want to get the lines following CAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a regex. I'm not sure from your question which pattern you are trying to match, so clarification would be helpful, but in the meantime, look in to [Regexs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

```
^(DOG\n.*\nCAT\n?)+$
```

This will match a series of lines, starting with DOG, a line break, some text, a line break, then CAT, repeating at least once.

Comment: I know that I need ragex but how can I use REGEX on file in line?
the pattern is Dog after it must be line and than CAT... after CAT can be oneline of text or DOG

Comment: oooooooooooooooooooooohhhhhhhh Editing to show my best guess at what you need.

Comment: I think that you understand what I need. 
now I need to read all the file to one String variable and check its?

Comment: You would use a Regex matcher on that string variable to verify it is in the format you need.